# Linear dependence of $w_1$, $\dots$, $w_n \in V$, $n > m$ of a vector space $V$ with basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Claim: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$. If $S = \{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}\subseteq V$ with $n>m$, then $T = \{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ is linearly dependent over $V$.

---

My main approach has been to prove by contradiction, but there are intermediate steps I'm having difficulty with.

$\textit{Proof}$.
Suppose $T$ is linearly independent over $V$. Then $T$ is either a basis of $V$ or it is not. If $T$ is a basis of $V$, then $n=m$, a contradiction. If $T$ is not a basis of $V$, then $T$ does not span $V$. So there exists an element $v\in V$ which cannot be obtained by any linear combination of elements $w_1$, $\dots$, $w_n$. I.e., there exists an element $v\in V$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_iw_i \neq v$$.
for all $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_n)\in K^n$. By assumption, $v \neq 0$. However, since $S$ is a basis of $V$, then there exists a linear combination of $v_1$, $\dots$, $v_m$ for which
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_iv_i = v$$
But this contradicts that $S$ is a basis of $V$, because this implies that $S$ is not linearly independent. Therefore, by contradiction we must have that $T$ is linearly dependent over $V$. Right?

Comment: You proved that $S \cup \{v\}$ is not linearly independent, not that $S$ is not linearly independent. So there is no contradiction yet.

Comment: which tools/lemmas do you know already? This is a pretty direct consequence of the dimension of a vector space being well defined (which you seem to be using in your proof, to contradict the set being a basis)

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove that $T=\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ is linearly dependent, we have to show that
$$(*) \ \ \ \ \ x_1w_1+x_2w_2+\cdots+x_nw_n=0$$
has a non-trivial solution. In other words, we have to show that there exist $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in K$, not all $0$, such that $(*)$ holds true.

Since  $S = \{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}\subseteq V$, we have
$$w_1=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i1}v_i,\\
w_2=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i2}v_i,\\
\vdots\\
w_n=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{in}v_i,$$
where $a_{ij}\in K$ with $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,\ldots,n$. Substituting these equations into $(*)$, we have
$$x_1\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i1}v_i\right)+x_2\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_{i2}v_i\right)+\cdots+x_n\left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_{in}v_i\right)=0\\
\Longrightarrow \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}x_j\right)v_1+\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{2j}x_j\right)v_2+\cdots+\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{mj}x_j\right)v_m=0.$$
Since $v_1,v_2, \dots, v_m$ is linearly independent, we obtain
$$a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\cdots+a_{1n}x_n=0;\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{2n}x_n=0;\\
\vdots\\
a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+\cdots+a_{mn}x_n=0.$$
Since $n>m$, then this system of linear equations is a homogeneous system with more unknowns than equations. Therefore, such homogeneous system has a non-trivial solution. This means that there exist $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\in K$, not all $0$, such that $(*)$ holds. Therefore, $T=\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ is linearly dependent.